# Как передать value инпутов в cookies ?

Tags: javascript, cookie

Задаю значение? через функцию setCookie и передаю value 4 инпутов в функцию storeValues.Потом достаю значение функцией getCookie, но в резльтате в  куках: undefined. Помогите пожалуйста !

```js
    const names = document.getElementById("name");
    const surname = document.getElementById("lastname");
    const age = document.getElementById("age");
    const phone = document.getElementById("phone");
    const search = document.getElementById("myInput");
    const add = document.getElementById("add_button");
    const table = document.getElementById("table");

    ///////////////////////create new user in table///////////////

        add.addEventListener('click', e => {
                let tr  = document.createElement("tr");
                let tdN = document.createElement("td");
                tdN.innerHTML = names.value;
            tr.appendChild(tdN);
                let tdSn = document.createElement("td");
                tdSn.innerHTML = surname.value;
                tr.appendChild(tdSn);
                let tdA = document.createElement("td");
                tdA.innerHTML = age.value;
                tr.appendChild(tdA);
                let tdP = document.createElement("td");
                tdP.innerHTML = phone.value;
                tr.appendChild(tdP);
                let tdB = document.createElement("td");
                tr.appendChild(tdB);
                let tdBd = document.createElement("button");
                tdBd.className = "delete";
                tdBd.innerHTML = "Yes";
                tdB.appendChild(tdBd);


            if(names.value === "" || surname.value === "" || age.value === "" || phone.value === "") {
                alert("fill in all the fields");
            }
            else  {
                table.appendChild(tr);

            }

            },false);

//////////////////////////////delete  old and new items in table/////////////////////////////
        document.addEventListener('click', e => {
            const elem  = e.target; ////
            if (elem.className === "delete") {
                elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elem.parentNode.parentNode);
            }
        },false);

////////////////////////// searching elements by name in table///////////////////
        let seek = e => {
          let filter, tr, td, i;
          filter = search.value.toUpperCase();
          tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

          for(i=0; i < tr.length; i++) {
              td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
              if (td) {
                  if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                      tr[i].style.display = "";
                  } else {
                      tr[i].style.display = "none";
                  }
              }
          }
        };


    ///////////////////////My example for using cookies//////////////////////////////
    let today = new Date();
    let expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days





    function setCookie(name, value)
    {
        document.cookie= name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();


        function storeValues(form)
        {
            setCookie("field1", form.names.value);
            setCookie("field2", form.surname.value);
            setCookie("field3", form.age.value);
            setCookie("field4", form.phone.value);
            return true;
        }
    }

    function getCookie(name)
    {
        let re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
        let value = re.exec(document.cookie);
        return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>address book</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
    <h2>My address book</h2>
    <img src="Phonebook-512.png" alt="Picture">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names" onkeyup="seek()">
</div>

<div class="body">
    <div class="listInfo">
        <table class="table_dark" id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <th>Surname:</th>
                <th>Age:</th>
                <th>Phone:</th>
                <th>Remove ?</th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Luke</td>
                <td>Skywoker</td>
                <td>68</td>
                <td>9379992</td>
                <td><button class="delete">Yes</button></td>

            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
<div class="InfoBlock">

        <h3>Add new contact:</h3>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="welcome-field">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="lastname">Lastname: </label>
                <input type="text" id="lastname" class="welcome-field">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="age" >Age: </label>
                <input type="number" id="age" class="welcome-field">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
                <input type="number" id="phone" class="welcome-field">
            </div>
            <button id="add_button" type="button" onclick="setCookie()">Add</button>


</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: функция `setCookie("field1", form.names.value);` устанавливает значения формы. В Вашем HTML, никакой формы я не нашел.